# How to input data to custom column in userprofile table when creating a new user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, user-accounts

I have added a custom column to my user profile table that is called CoID (int).
When I want to create a new user I want to send the value 1 to CoID, but I am experiencing some trouble and cant get it to work properly.

I am using the standard account tables from mvc4.

Here are some of my code

AccountModel.cs

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Custom)]
    [Display(Name = "CoID")]
    [Compare("CoID", ErrorMessage = "plese insert CoID")]
    public int CoID { get; set; }
}


[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int CoID { get; set; }
}
```

AccountController.cs

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        model.CoID = 1;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            try
            {
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, model.CoID);
                WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

When executing this code i am getting this error:

The custom Data-type string cannot be null or empty.

Comment: What does you call to WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection look like?

Answer (score 0):

I think your call to WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount might need looking at.

Perhaps the following might work better:

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, 
    new { CoID = model.CoID });
```

As from the anonymous object it can work out what values you're trying to assign to what field names. Otherwise you're just passing through the value and it doesn't know where to put it.

Comment: I tried your solution and it did not fix my problem, the same error message is still displayed when i try to create a new user. All i want to accomplish is to insert a value to the CoID coulmn.

Comment: Just spotted another potential issue - you have a compare data annotation on your model. I think this might be a copy and paste mistake since you are only trying to compare it with itself.

Comment: Otherwise more details of the exception could be useful - what do you see when you debug, what line does the exception occur at and are you seeing CoID correctly populated on your model at post back?

Answer (score 0):

Remove [DataType(DataType.Custom)] or change to [DataType("CoID")].